# Hangfire queuing up missed schedules

Tags: c#, hangfire

I've got an issue with scheduled jobs, where if for some reason a job is scheduled, but the application isn't running (says it crashed, or we're on local dev).

It will then queue the schedules that should have run.

> For example, if it's **daily**, and my local version hasn't run for **3**
>   days, it will then try and queue **3** scheduled jobs up

Is there a way to disable it?